# "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" on fonts urls. CloudFront with Lightsail Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-lightsail, w3-total-cache

I'm using cloudfront on lightsail on my website https://topshelfaquatics.com with the help of W3Total Cache. I've used all the possible ways like allowing headers (Origin) in Cloudfront but still it is not solving.
Can you suggest me a solution?

[image]

Comment: its cors policy restricted external URL

Comment: Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT"

Comment: Where exactly can we see these errors? On the homepage of the site you've linked I see no such errors

Answer (score 0):

Please look at your network tab in the developer tools. This will give you information about the http calls. Most of the time the browser give this error when it's a xhr (ajax) call and no Access-Control-* headers has been set in the response. In order to solve this there are two possibilities:

1. Do not use xhr requests for fonts, so do not load fonts from JS. Use the default methods in html/css for loading fonts.
2. Add the required Access-Control-* headers to the http response. This requires involvement of cloudfont.net, so this solution might not be very realistic.

Answer (score 0):

Cross-Origin Resource Sharing - CORS - is a mechanism that use some additional HTTP headers to inform the browser that access resource has different domain from origin.

You try access resource at Cloud Front, without setup the allowed domains int, below a example that enable CORS, for HTTP method GET and all headers, in Cloud Front:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
  <CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://topshelfaquatics.com</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>1800</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
  </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Answer (score -2):

Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that allows restricted resources on a web page to be requested from another domain outside the domain from which the first resource was served. ... Certain "cross-domain" requests, notably Ajax requests, are forbidden by default by the same-origin security policy.

Comment: How is this *the answer* to the question?

Answer (score -3):

**Chrome browser install Extension:**

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en